# Storing cart object in a session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cart

I want to store a cart object in a session. In a cart controller:

```
def new 
  @cart = Cart.new
  @cart.total_price = 0
  session[:cart] = @cart
  @cart
end
```

In a model I have only this code:

```
attr_accessor :total_price
```

On the main page I'm trying to create a new cart if it's not created yet.

```
<% unless session[:cart] %>
  <%= session[:cart] = Cart.new %>
<% end %>
<%= session[:cart].total_price %>
```

So it should print total price of the items in the cart(temporarily zero because I haven't implemented items in the cart yet) but it doesn't. What's the problem?

Comment: true, see http://www.quarkruby.com/2007/10/21/sessions-and-cookies-in-ruby-on-rails#slimitations to know why. It's somewhat better to store a cart id.